# SQL Server Doubts when adding work shift 3 (SUM)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good morning Srs I am a beginner in SQL Server and I have a question:
Do you know how to make a sum (SUM) of Shift 3 of a company and organize it by day? The problem is that shift 3 ends the next day **(starts at 10 pm and ends at 6 am the next day)**, so I'm trying to make an exception only for shift 3 that on the current day disregards the values ​​obtained before 6 am and disappears from 10 pm until 6 am the next day.
Below is the script that I already made and the result obtained In the result obtained in Turn 3 today (the 14th is already with data produced, but this data should be from shift 3 of yesterday)
If someone helps me, thank you

```
SELECT 
STR(DAY(E3TimeStamp),2) + '/' + STR(MONTH(E3TimeStamp),1) + '/' + STR(YEAR(E3TimeStamp),4) AS Data,
Maquina AS Maquina,
Parametro AS Código,
ROUND(sum(Metrica),2) AS 'Metrica Total' ,
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Turno = 1 THEN Metrica ELSE 0 END),2) As 'Metrica Turno 01',
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Turno = 2 THEN Metrica ELSE 0 END),2) As 'Metrica Turno 02',
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Turno = 3 THEN Metrica ELSE 0 END),2) As 'Metrica Turno 03'
FROM Tab_Dados_Escolha
GROUP BY 
YEAR(E3TimeStamp), MONTH(E3TimeStamp),DAY(E3TimeStamp), Maquina, Parametro
```

Result obtained from the script above:
[image]

Result that should occur (Shift 03 was added to the previous day, as it has not yet started today):
[image]

Comment: I don't see any condition in your code?! also provide sample data and desired output as well

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic.  Your description is not unambiguous.

Comment: Start over. First, forget about trying to format your resultset in a "pretty" fashion. Just select the date (E3TimeStamp) directly for now. Probably you need to cast that to DATE for your grouping and output purposes. Note that including that column along with your month, day, and year expressions in the group by clause is both redundant and contributing to your problems. Ordering by DAY in the OVER clause also seems logically flawed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a similar challenge in our business, where the new production day does not begin until 4:30 AM. We handled it by creating a function that will return which day the timestamp should be counted toward.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[usf_start_date_parm]
(
    @start_date DATETIME
)
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
        
    DECLARE @OutDate    DATE
            ,@InDate    DATETIME = @start_date
            ,@StartTime VARCHAR(10) = '06:00'
            
    SELECT  @OutDate = CASE
                WHEN CAST(@InDate AS time) < @StartTime THEN CAST(DATEADD(Day,-1,CAST(@InDate AS DATE)) AS DATETIME)+@StartTime
                ELSE CAST(CAST(@InDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME)+@StartTime
                END
            
    RETURN @OutDate
END
```

Use would be as such, but without sample data to test against, you're kind of on your own as far as implementation.

```
SELECT 
STR(DAY(dbo.usf_start_date_parm(E3TimeStamp)),2) + '/' + STR(MONTH(dbo.usf_start_date_parm(E3TimeStamp)),1) + '/' + STR(YEAR(dbo.usf_start_date_parm(E3TimeStamp)),4) AS Data,
Maquina AS Maquina,
Parametro AS Código,
ROUND(sum(Metrica),2) AS 'Metrica Total' ,
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Turno = 1 THEN Metrica ELSE 0 END),2) As 'Metrica Turno 01',
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Turno = 2 THEN Metrica ELSE 0 END),2) As 'Metrica Turno 02',
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Turno = 3 THEN Metrica ELSE 0 END),2) As 'Metrica Turno 03'
FROM Tab_Dados_Escolha
GROUP BY 
YEAR(dbo.usf_start_date_parm(E3TimeStamp)), MONTH(dbo.usf_start_date_parm(E3TimeStamp)),DAY(dbo.usf_start_date_parm(E3TimeStamp)), Maquina, Parametro
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for help, im simulate this code and compilation errors are found, i'm trying to remove this errors now

Comment: If it was helpful, please mark as answer by clicking the check box next to the vote arrows :-)

Comment: This answer was helpful but still hasn't solved the problem because I couldn't simulate your code because there were errors in compiling the code

Comment: Any errors, it was my fault, thanks for help!

Comment: An inline Table Function is much more performant